# Is there a way to access WTForms RadioField labels from within a view function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I'm developing a simple web application, and I have some forms with `wtforms.RadioField`'s in them. I am wondering if there is a way to access the field label from a view function in the same way as I access the field data.

From the [wtforms documentation](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/stable/fields.html#wtforms.fields.RadioField), RadioFields (and SelectFields) both have the argument `choices` with is a list of (value, label) pairs. So, if I have a simple form

```py
import wtforms
import flask_wtf

class SimpleForm(flask_wtf.FlaskForm):
    select = wtforms.RadioField(
        'Select', 
        choices=[(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c')], 
        validators=[wtforms.validators.DataRequired()]
    )
    submit = wtforms.SubmitField('submit')
```

And after rendering the form in html, the view function would be

```py
@app.route('/select', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def select():
    form = SimpleForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        value = form.select.data
        label = form.select.label  # I wish I could do this
```

I hope it's clear what I'm asking. currently, I am using another function with a dictionary of values that map to the `choices` parameter above to get the label, but it seems like there should be a better way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to directly ask the RadioField for the label (or tuple) of the selected item. However, you can ask the field for its choices and determine the selected one from that:

```
value = form.select.data
choices = dict(form.select.choices)
label = choices[value]
```

It's one extra line, but still quite concise. Using this approach would be worthwhile if your field's choices change all the time and you don't want to have to provide the state needed to recalculate them.